# With SurfaceView and 4 Canvas Images How to find which image was touched ?

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, touch-event

I would like to know how to find which specific image was touched on my SurfaceView Class which has four different images moving from one corner to another roulette style ???

I plan on launching different Activities with each image.

-Thanks You for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (still kinda a n00b) there isn't a "getImage" (or equivelant) method for `Canvas`. So what I did is create a `Rect` at the dimensions of each Image or Bitmap. Here is an example of an on-screen, canvas-drawn d-pad for character control in a game project I'm doing:

```
public class World extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

Rect viewRect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    viewImage1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.left_key), 50, 50,
            true);

    viewImage2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.right_key), 50, 50,
            true);
                                //left,top,right,bottom
    viewRect1 = new Rect(viewImage1X, viewImage1Y, viewImage1X+viewImage1Width,
            viewImage1Y+viewImage1Height);

                               //left,top,right,bottom
    viewRect2 = new Rect(viewImage2X, viewImage2Y, viewImage2X+viewImage2Width,
            viewImage2Y+viewImage2Height);
```

**Then in your onTouch() method:**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        // Rectangle surrounding your view1 is touched
        if (x <= viewRect1.right && x >= viewRect1.left
                && y >= viewRect1.top && y <= viewRect1.bottom) {
                    // Example Activity:
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.Activity");
                    startActivity(intent);

            }

                    // Rectangle surrounding your view2 is touched
               //if onTouch was NOT in viewRect1, check here. Otherwise will be disregarded
        else if (x <= viewRect2.right && x >= viewRect2.left
                && y >= viewRect2.top && y <= viewRect2.bottom) {
                    // Example Activity:
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.Activity2");
                    startActivity(intent);

            }

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help from one NOOB to another.  Can you explain a little how the if statement "if (x <= bLeftRect.right && x >= bLeftRect.left
                && y >= bLeftRect.top && y <= bLeftRect.bottom) {"... will distinguish one image from another ?  what will be the differing marker ??? in the values of the "if statement"...a little confused...thanks again.

Comment: thanks for clarifying just had to be sure.  I went down this path with the following code for..."  if (eventX >= (x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (x + bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
    
   if (eventY >= (y - bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (y <= (y + bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
   // droid touched   
setTouched(true);"...but for some reason it only works for any images that lands top left or top right ??   if any image lands on bottom left or bottom right it launches two activities as apposed to one.

Comment: not sure where exactly you want that "else if" to go here is the full statement ..."public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
  if (eventX >= (x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (x + bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
   if (eventY >= (y - bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (y <= (y + bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
    
    setTouched(true);
   } else {
    setTouched(false);
   }
  } else {
   setTouched(false);
  }

 }"...thanks again

Comment: Updated Answer, hopefully that helps. Question though: Why are you saying "if (eventX >= (x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2)... This is your problem. You need to check if eventX is greater than the left side of the rectangle && less than the right side of the rectangle surrounding your view. The same for eventY

Comment: You are MY HERO...George Orwell, Jonas Salk, M.L.K. and now MattMatt  !!!!!!!  Thaaannnnkkk YOU SOOO MUCH !!!!!!  You caught it with "This is your problem...." hahahah ..it was ...you saved my weekend.  I wish could buy you a six pack.  If you have a paypal email send it my way.  thx for the patience.

Comment: Lol, no need but thanks anyways, that's what this site is for. I am glad I could help. All I ask for is you to accept the answer if it is what you were looking for. I cleaned up my useless comments as well to help keep this clean and to-the-point.

Comment: Sorry bout that I was so elated you caught my error I forgot to accept and up vote.  Happy travels @MattMatt.